# Python solve subset of linear equations

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, differential-equations

So I know about sympy and numpy’s linear algebra solver, but what I am trying to do is different. I don’t have the equations to form a solvable matrix so I can solve with those libraries, so I’m trying to solve for a single variable by combining 2 or more equations. For example:

A+B+C = 2
B+C = 1

By combining these equations we can see that we get A+1 = 2 or A = 1.

How can I go about implement something like this in python since I can’t just create a matrix and solve it? The end goal is to end up with a single variable being equal to either 0 or 1, and if that’s not possible then just the shortest form it can go to by combining the equations. To add, the variables coefficients will always be 1, so in other words there will never be something like 2A+B = 3 .

Comment: You will probably be better off asking it at the mathematics stack exchange. Essentially it sounds like you need to eliminate the "right" variables (in your example denote D=B+C) to get the expressions you want. This is general linear algebra, nothing to do with python in particular.

Comment: In the general case finding an elimination can probably be done using Gram-Schmidt on the colspace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from sympy import *
a, b, c = symbols('a, b, c')
f1 = a+b+c
f2 = b+c
result = solve([f1-2, f2-1], (a, b, c))
```

**Output:**

```
{b: 1 - c, a: 1}
```